# Prove that $R =\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$ is a Euclidean domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

An exercise in my abstract-algebra class asks me that

1. > Prove that $R =\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$ is a Euclidean domain.
2. > If $u$ is a unit of $R$ , then 
   >   $$u=(\sqrt{5}+2)^n \;\;\text{or}\; \;u=-(\sqrt{5}+2)^n$$
   >   for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Firstly I want to show that $R$ is a Euclidean domain with respect to the following function:
$$\varphi: R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}_{+}: a+b\phi \mapsto |a^2 + ab - b^2|$$
where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

But there's some problem in finishing them,  any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Edit：

To prove $R$ is a Euclidean we must to check that

1. $\varphi(\alpha ) \leq \varphi(\alpha \beta  )$ for $\beta \neq 0$;
2. for any $\alpha, \beta \in R, \beta \neq 0$ ,there exist $q,r \in R$ such that $\alpha =q \beta +r$ with $r =0 $or $\varphi(r) < \varphi (\beta)$.

For $(1)$ obviously.

For $(2)$, we look for $q$ and $r$ such that $\alpha =q \beta +r$ and write this as $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=q+\frac{r}{\beta}$, here $q,r \in \mathbb {Q}$. Then 
$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\mu +\nu \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
for some $\mu ,\nu \in \mathbb {Q}$(since $\mathbb{Q}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$ is a field .)However, I tried to find possible integers $m,n$ to approximate $\mu ,\nu$ to test  $\varphi(r) < \varphi (\beta)$, but failed.

Comment: What did you try, and where in your proof did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to show that $R$ is Euclidean with respect to the function .

Comment: Right, but what did you try? Why didn't it work? It's much easier to help you if I know what you've tried.