# ring of integers with golden ratio

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, golden-ratio

How to show that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ is a principal ideal domain (where $\phi$ is the golden ratio)?

I want to prove that using as elementary algebra-level notions as possible.

Give some advice!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ is Euclidean, and hence a PID. The proof is by elementary algebra.

Reference: [Prove that $R =\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$ is a Euclidean domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531002/prove-that-r-mathbbz-left-frac1-sqrt52-right-is-a-euclidean-domai?rq=1)

The details of the proof are very similar to the ones of this post:

[Proof that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is a Euclidean Domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517348/proof-that-mathbb-z-sqrt3-is-a-euclidean-domain)

Comment: Thank you for linked. That's great.